# Joining attributes from points to polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, attribute-joins, point-in-polygon

I have a polygon layer without data, and a point layer with attributes.

Each point is contained in one polygon, and I would like to have the data from the point layer joint in the polygon layer, so every polygon has the data from the point contained in it.

Is this possible with QGIS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the processing toolbox(Under processing ->toolbox), you can find the tool "join attributes by location" (under
QGIS geo algorithms -> Vector general tools -> join attributes by location)

[image: pic of the tool at imgur]

You can set the target layer and the join layer. You would also need to tick the geometric predicate which would be "contains" in your case.

You also have additional options if you want any statistics like sum and mean but you will not need them so you can leave this field empty. You can also decide if you want to keep only matching records or all records of the target layer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check the spatialJoin Plugin